# Azure Stream Analytics - No output

Tags: azure-stream-analytics, azure-iot-hub

I have a Stream job that uses reference data and retrieved device data from an IOT Hub. The code is below;

```
WITH AggregatedValues AS
(
SELECT
    iot1.DeviceId,
    iot1.SensorId,
    MAX(CAST(iot1.Timestamp AS DateTime)) AS [DateTime], 
    CASE WHEN ch1.IsActive = 1 AND ch1.AggregateType = 1
    THEN SUM(iot1.SensorValue)
    WHEN ch1.IsActive = 1 AND ch1.AggregateType = 3
    THEN MAX(iot1.SensorValue)
    WHEN ch1.IsActive = 1 AND ch1.AggregateType = 4
    THEN MIN(iot1.SensorValue)
    ELSE AVG(iot1.SensorValue)
    END [AggValue]
FROM 
MecfabIoTHub iot1
JOIN DeviceRef1 ch1
ON iot1.DeviceId = ch1.DeviceId AND iot1.SensorId = ch1.SensorId
GROUP BY iot1.DeviceId, iot1.SensorId,ch1.IsActive, ch1.AggregateType, TumblingWindow(minute,5)
)

SELECT  
ch2.DeviceName,
ch2.SensorType,
ch2.SensorName,
ch2.TriggerVal,
ch2.TriggerState,
ch2.AggregateType,
ch2.IsActive,
AggregatedValues.[AggValue],

CASE WHEN ch2.IsActive = 1 AND ch2.TriggerState = 1 AND AggregatedValues.AggValue >= ch2.TriggerVal
THEN ch2.AlertDesc
WHEN ch2.IsActive = 1 AND ch2.TriggerState = 2 AND AggregatedValues.AggValue <= ch2.TriggerVal
THEN ch2.AlertDesc
ELSE NULL
END AS Alert

INTO
BLOBSensorData
FROM 
AggregatedValues
JOIN DeviceRef1 ch2
ON ch2.DeviceId = AggregatedValues.DeviceId  AND ch2.SensorId = AggregatedValues.SensorId
```

I have no issues with the reference data and all fields have been checked to be as expected (DeviceId is same from the reference data to the device data, etc.). Output I am just placing in a blob to test. Not sure what is going on but there is no output being generated. All inputs and outputs have been tested.

I also have checked the data coming from the IOTHub using the device explorer and there are definitely events being received by the IOT Hub.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that you output name in the query is correct, e.g. `INTO BLOBSensorData`?

I had this problem before because the output name in my query was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested your query creates as described in the 'Diagnose and solve problems' from your stream analytics job? Maybe the join does not work.

Regards,

Filip